# How to fix the jQuery 1.8 “unsupported pseudo: all” error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

It works on jquery 1.3 but when I try to replace it with 1.8 I get the “unsupported pseudo: all” error:

Here is my current code:

```
 $(function () {
            $('input[id$=btnAdd]').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // Assuming you get a JSON object from a service
                var lenBefore = $('select[id$=DDL] :all').length;
                var obj = { "6": "Item6", "7": "Item7", "8": "Item8" };
                $.each(obj, function (value, text) {
                    $('select[id$=DDL]').append($('<option></option>').val(value).html(text))
                });
                var lenAfter = $('select[id$=DDL] :all').length;
                $("#para").html("<b>" + (lenAfter - lenBefore) + "</b>" + " new items were added");
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            });
        });
```

Your answers would be of great help.

Comment: What is wrong with `var lenAfter = $('select[id$=DDL]').length;`

Comment: Another option would be to have a `var counter = 0;` and in the `each`, do `counter++` to use the variable later on, to display the amount of new items added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `$('select[id$=DDL] option')` or `$('select[id$=DDL] *')` or `$('select[id$=DDL]').children()`

Answer (score 1):

its because jquery does not supports the `:all` selector

as you can see in [jquery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) there is not any selector like `:all`